# Show folder name from a path

Tags: c#, wpf, directory, directoryinfo

I have a problem and I think you can help me.

I want to compare two directories the following code works but I have a problem to show the result. I want to make a list of steps that show how to make the structure of both directories show as same.

I have this code and I dont know how to add the folder name from directory 1 + the Filenames:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir1 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathA);
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathB);

// Take a snapshot of the file system.
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var v in queryList1Only)
{
    listbox_2f.Items.Add("Create: "+ dir2.FullName+ "\\" +   v.Name);
}
```

How I can solve this problem that I can add the foldernames from directory 1 to listbox.

Ok i will give you an example expect I have a directory like: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1 in this directory are subdirectories and files now I have to show a list how to make the structure of these directory same as of C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\Test2 so when I have in Test1 in example the folders Test12 and in these a text123.txt file with the path: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1\Test12\text123.txt who could I add in the listbox something like "Create: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2\Test12\text123.txt" Of course the path isn`t everytime the same

Comment: Just peek a bit more at the FileInfo class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

It also has methods/properties like DirectoryName (which you should apply on dir1 or any file in list1.

And you probably want the 'Name' instead of the FullName.

    string   fileName = @"C:\TMP\log.txt";
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
    if (!fileInfo.Exists)
    {
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} has a directoryName of {1}",
        fileName, fileInfo.DirectoryName);

Comment: What is your exact problem? Show us an example, it's not very clear what you want to do.

Comment: @MarcelN.      Ok i will give you an example expect I have a directory like: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1 in this directory are subdirectories and files now I have to show a list how to make the structure of these directory same as of C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\Test2 so when I have in Test1 in example the folders Test12 and in these a text123.txt file with the path: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1\Test12\text123.txt who could I add in the listbox something like "Create: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2\Test12\text123.txt" Of course the path isn`t everytime the same

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract the folder (in other word, directory) name from the path, you can use `Path.GetDirectoryName()` method as detailed in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Also, refer to the C# usage example given in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
string filePath = @"C:\MyDir\MySubDir\myfile.ext";
string directoryName;
int i = 0;

while (filePath != null)
{
    directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
    Console.WriteLine("GetDirectoryName('{0}') returns '{1}'", filePath, directoryName);
    filePath = directoryName;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        filePath = directoryName + @"\";  // this will preserve the previous path
    }
    i++;
}
/*
This code produces the following output:

GetDirectoryName('C:\MyDir\MySubDir\myfile.ext') returns 'C:\MyDir\MySubDir'
GetDirectoryName('C:\MyDir\MySubDir') returns 'C:\MyDir'
GetDirectoryName('C:\MyDir\') returns 'C:\MyDir'
GetDirectoryName('C:\MyDir') returns 'C:\'
GetDirectoryName('C:\') returns ''
*/
```

Regards,